# Как протестировать Optional?

Tags: android, kotlin, юнит-тесты

```
class CompanyCommandTest {
private val companyId = 3L
private val company = createEmptyCompany(companyId)

@Before
fun setUp() {
    setupRxSchedulersForTests()
}

@Test
fun takeFromStorage() {

val storage = mock<CompanyStorage> {
    on { getcompany(any()) } doReturn company
}

val command = CompanyCommand(storage)

command.getCompany(companyId).test().assertValue(company.toOptional())
verify(storage).getCompany(companyId) 
}
}
```

В данном тесте ошибка в методе assertValue, ошибка заключается в том, что command.getSurvey(surveyId) не является равным survey.toOptimal. Предполагаю что ошибка в том, что объекты ссылаются на разные участки памяти (хотя поля идентичны). Поправьте меня если не прав и каким образом тестировать такой метод?

createEmptyCompany() - это метод который возвращает объект Company

Метод тест находится в классе Single
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из приведенного кода мало что понятно. Что за `createEmptyCompany()` и `test()` у него? Про участки памяти я так понял что вы пытаетесь сказать о двух обьектах с идентичным содержимым? Читайте здесь: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja здравствуйте, обновил ответ

Comment: Метку `Rx` в след. раз не забывайте, а то сходу не всегда догадаешься.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja хорошо, спасибо )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так понимаю вопрос в том, как сравнить значения в объекте типа `Optional`. По сути `Optional` - является некоторой коробкой предоставляемая стандартной библиотекой, не нужно тестировать сам `Optional`, необходимо сравнивать значения внутри этой коробки.

`observer.test().assertValue { actualValue-> expectedValue.equals(actualValue) }`

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, теперь я узнал как получать значение из этой коробки :)